# What is the function of the word "boats" in this sentence?

Tags: clauses

> For instance, they can learn that boats float and can practice ways to make **boats** move across water.

Is it a subject or an object (the bolded word)?

Comment: This sentence is a complicated one! Note, we're talking about a small clause inside a longer sentence. The subject of the whole *sentence* is "they," and it has two main verbs, "learn" and "practice." We can simplify it: "They can learn and practice ways." "Boats" is part of a clause that's at a deeper level than the main subject and objects of the sentence.

Comment: @Bubbles  "Boats" is object of "make".  See my comment below to Andy Bonner.

Comment: This complicated and highly contested question should NOT have been moved to ELL. It is a classic problem in linguistics.

Comment: Like I said (and some mod removed), boats is used in two different ways here.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple clauses in this sentence. Some of the clauses are infinitive and don't have explicit subjects.  When a clause doesn't have an explicit subject, you can understand the subject from context.

The structure with "make" is "... make {object} {bare infinitive}"  For example "make him do something" or "make me be something".  The word "him" or "me" is necessarily in the object form. The bare infinitive is a subordinate clause.

This word also provides the *understood* subject of the bare infinitive. So "boats" is the object of the verb "make". But we also understand the subject of verb move is "boats".

Comment: I would not analyse it that way. I would say that object of *make* is the entire clause, and the infinitive clause **does** have a subject: it's *boats*. *Boats* is not the object of anything.

Comment: I hear you, but that analysis has problems.  You need to explain why this word has the object form in "make me do it", and note that the infinitive can be dropped to give "You can't make me!".  This can be compared to sentences with -ing verbs  like "Hear me singing it" (in which me is object form and provides understood object to the gerund/participle) compared with "Hear my singing of it".  Grammatically "boats" is an object, but it's main role is that of "affected" in the clause "move across water".

Comment: Yes, "to make boats move across water" is a catenative construction with "boats" as raised object.

Comment: @tchrist This is a big and once highly-contended issue in linguistics. This should definitely never have been moved from EL&U. Or if so, it should have gone to Linguistics!

Comment: @tchrist Transformationalists used to argue that *boat* started off as the subject in the subordinate clause and then got "raised" to the object of *make* in the surface form. Kind of like it died and went to heaven.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. For us to migrate this question again is not possible directly. You have to close it here to bounce the migration back to ELU. From there it could in theory be re-migrated to Linguistics, but only by a moderator. You'll want to re-look at my first sentence in this comment; notice that *us* is the subject of the infinitive clause, and the infinitive clause the subject of the main clause. There are no prepositional phrases in that first sentence: neither *for* nor *to* is a preposition there. To pretend otherwise would require making a prepositional phrase a subject.

Comment: @tchrist I think it should have stayed on EL&U, but never mind. I don't understand the preposition comment?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I find analysing *make him go, let him go, ask him to go* as a verb taking an infinitive clause with its own subject as its object to be the most parsimonious analysis. Infinitive clauses with overt subjects need a *for..to* complementizer in the subject position but not elsewhere. I am aware that other analyses are possible here, but they are not parsimonious.

Comment: @tchrist It's parsimonious till you start passivising the various clauses etc! Yes. There's no good middle ground here and, in fact, no good analysis. They're all good-bad.  I'm  with you-ish, but not for *ask*, though. *I asked him to go* and *I asked for him to go* seem to have a different meaning, arguably due to *for him to go* being a clausal complement unlike *him to go*. I'm sympathetic re the rest, though. You might enjoy section 6 of this review of CGEL by Bas Aarts, in which the whole Chomsky 73 v Postal 74 battle is discussed: [Grammatici Certant](https://tinyurl.com/ynh386uh)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  That's because there's no *for..to* complementizer unless it's the subject; otherwise you've got a "phrasal" verb that ends in *for*, like *to wait for* has. The syntactic test is easy here: *For him to go isn't what I was waiting for*. Notice that you have to "double" it.

Comment: @tchrist There's no *for* unless the infinitival clause has a subject. But according to your analysis 'him' ***is*** a subject in *I asked him to go*! In contrast, in *I asked for him to go/for the cheese to be brought in*, everyone agrees that *him* and *the cheese* are subjects of the nonfinite clauses because they occur after infinitival *for*. Compare *I asked the cheese to be brought in.*

Comment: So it's difficult every way you look at it, really.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, nonfinite clauses whose subjects are personal pronouns inflect these into object case: *Me going there alone is easier than us going there together.*  Trying to tell native speakers that they mustn't be allowed to say that sort of thing won't stop them from doing so—and say it they most certainly do, so we need an analysis that affords us a parsimonious model of what's going on here syntactically. This still seems easier to understand analysed my way, at least to&for me. I guess we should ask this on [linguistics.se] if we really want to get good answers.

Comment: @tchrist I disagree. "To make boats move across water" is a catenative construction, where "boats" is the syntactic object of "make" as well as the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate infinitival clause "move across water".

Answer (score -1):

"Boats" would be the object, whereas "they" would be the subject. It is often difficult when trying to decipher object/subject when the sentence is in reference to others.

Comment: Sorry, this is off-base. It's true that "they" is the subject of the overall sentence, but whatever "boats"' function is, it's a function within a smaller clause. The sentence is not "they move boats." I haven't answered yet because I'm actually not sure of the right terminology.

Comment: @AndyBonner And it's not what James K wrote in their answer. James K's answer agrees completely with Sean's.

Comment: @BillJ I think Sean deserves an upvote!

Comment: Sorry guys, in my opinion James' answer has the important part: "There are multiple clauses in this sentence." And "boats" is *not* "the object" of the sentence. "THE" two objects are the word "ways" and (I guess) the phrase "that boats float." Nothing personal, but this answer doesn't have enough detail.

Comment: @AndyBonner OK, right, I see that. (Although in the 'make'-clause , the subject is understood to be *they* through a relationship of control, and *boat* is the object (in most analyses). So it's not clear to me which clause Sean is talking about, given that OP is specifically interested in the *boat* in the *make*-VP. Certainly ot worthy of a downvote, imo)

Comment: @AndyBonnerThe OP asked a simple question about the function of the second instance of "boats", which they even emboldened. This "boats" is the syntactic object of "make" as well as the semantic (understood) subject of the subordinate clause "move across water".